# Is it possible to auto-stop the first audio when playing the second?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to create an Android App using Cordova to play sounds.

Sounds are working without problem. Except that when I add two sounds, the first I play is the only one to be play. Even when clicking on the button of the other sound it plays the first played.

```
        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var my_media = new playAudio();
        }

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio(src) {
            if (my_media == null) {
                // Create Media object from src
                my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
            } // else play current audio
            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                        // success callback
                        function(position) {
                            if (position > -1) {
                                setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                            }
                        },
                        // error callback
                        function(e) {
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                        }
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        // Pause audio
        //
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        //
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        //
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/1.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('https://ia800902.us.archive.org/23/items/tagot/rain.mp3');">Play Audio2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
<p id="audio_position"></p>
```

What I am trying to get is to play for example 5 sounds and whenever I click on one of them the one playing stop immediately.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The first sound continues to play because you are checking the below condition which returns `true` after the first audio is played.

```
if (my_media == null) {
  my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Instead, if you need to play multiple audio files, use an object.

```
my_media = {}; // init the play object

function playAudio(src, id) {

  if (!my_media[id]) { // check if media already created
    my_media[id] = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
  }

  my_media[id].play();

}

playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/1.mp3', 458);
playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/2.mp3', 33);
playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/3.mp3', 44);
```

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but didn't work. I will be so grateful if you can answer with the full code adding your solution to my code above. And it will be more helpful if you can add two sounds and not just one. Thanks

Comment: can you specify to what did not work? did you give 2 different ID?

Comment: just to be clear: I want to add for example 3 audio files and play each of them using "onclick" with a unique button.

Comment: Thank you... it is working. But how to link playing of each sound to an "onclick" button.

Comment: feel free to accept this answer if it has solved the issue,

Comment: add as a normal click `onclick="playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/1.mp3', 555);"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I used your code:

```
       function playAudio(src) {
          my_media = {}; // init the play object

function playAudio(src, id) {

  if (!my_media[id]) { // check if media already created
    my_media[id] = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
  }
  my_media[id].play();
}

playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/1.mp3', 1);
playAudio('https://ia800902.us.archive.org/23/items/tagot/rain.mp3', 2);
```

- The audio is auto-playing which I don't want. But use onclick to play
  it.

Comment: remove this as it should be a comment, not an answer mate.

Answer (score 0):

This code autoplay the sound:

```
function playAudio(src) {
my_media = {}; // init the play object

function playAudio(src, id) {

  if (!my_media[id]) { // check if media already created
    my_media[id] = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
  }

  my_media[id].play();

}

playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/1.mp3', 458')
```

But When I move the src to link to an "onclick" button, it stop working:

```
<a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/1.mp3', 458');">Play Audio</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working perfectly:

```
          function onDeviceReady() {
            var my_media = new playAudio();
        }

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
my_media = {}; // init the play object

   function playAudio(src, id) {
     if (!my_media[id]) { // check if media already created
       my_media[id] = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
     }

     my_media[id].play();

   }
```

But when I play the second sound, the first does not stop.

the whole code:

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            var my_media = new playAudio();
        }

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

        // Play audio
        //
my_media = {}; // init the play object

   function playAudio(src, id) {
     if (!my_media[id]) { // check if media already created
       my_media[id] = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
     }

     my_media[id].play();

   }

 //playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/media/1.mp3');

        // Pause audio
        //
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        //
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        //
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }
```